# Statements going against the grain of Riemann Hypothesis (R.H.)

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis

Let  $M(N) := \sum_{n=1}^N \mu(n)$

It is known that bounding $M(N)$ by $N^{1/2+\epsilon}$ implies R.H.

A bound of $M(N)$ by $K\sqrt N$ for say $ K\ge2 $ is also sufficient. $K = 1$ is excluded as Mertens's conjecture is false.

Suppose you show that for each $\epsilon > 0$ there are infinitely many values N such that $M(N) > N^{1-\epsilon}$.

**Question 1:** Does this invalidate R.H.?

**Question 2:** How does a result like  $ M(N)>N^{0,99} $ for any 
$N>N_o$ for some $N_o$ stand with R.H.?

In the second question does it kill some well accepted heuristics about R.H.?

Most texts about number theory or R.H. give sufficient conditions and discuss chains of necessity leading to R.H., But I found little about falsity of R.H. (the "heretic side" as called somewhere in Tao's blog).

**Notational remark:** Mathematicians should use $\dot \mu(N)$ instead of $M(N)$, saving symbols and brain but not eyes (because LaTeX point is too small).

Comment: Yes to Q1, no to Q2, of course, because then the statement that $M(x) \ll_{\varepsilon} x^{1/2 + \varepsilon}$ would be false, and this is equivalent to RH. Basically, if $\limsup_{x \to \infty} |M(x)|x^{-\Theta} > 0$ for some $\Theta > 1/2$, then RH is false.

Comment: OK I agree that my question are a bit simplistic, I thought a mere specific epsilon was enough. Considering how far we are ( N/logN) I feel justified in my mistake. Sorry for the disturbance though.

Comment: If $M(n) = O(n^{a})$ then there is $N,C$ such that for every $n > N$ : $|M(n)| < C n^{a}$. Of course $M(n) > n^{1-\epsilon}$ for infinitely many $n$ contradicts this statement

Answer (score 5):

In fact many texts give *equivalent* statements to RH in terms of $M(N)$ and related arithmetic functions. In particular, RH is equivalent to the following: for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $N_0$ depending on $\epsilon$, such that for any $N>N_0$ we have $|M(N)|<N^{1/2+\epsilon}$.

Informally, this means that if RH fails, then $|M(N)|$ is occasionally much larger than $\sqrt{N}$, and vice versa. It is a subtle question how large $|M(N)|$ can really get if RH holds. For the state-of-the-art in this direction and for what more can be expected, see [Soundararajan's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.0723).

Comment: Perfect: thanks for the paper and the removal of a misconception of mine.

Answer (score 4):

If you have $M(N) > N^{0.99}$ for infinitely many $N$ then this means there is a an exceptional zero with real part $\geq 0.99$, that therefore invalidates RH.

As to the order of growth of $M(x)$ a well substantiated conjectured due to Steve Gonek and Nathan Ng, is that 
$$
\limsup_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{|M(x)|}{\sqrt{x} (\log\log\log x)^{5/4}} = B 
$$
for some finite constant $B > 0$, see http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~nathanng/RESEARCH/mobius2b.pdf on p. 9. In particular this implies that there is no finite constant $K > 0$ such that $|M(x)| < K \sqrt{x}$ for all $x$.

Finally your notational suggestion is bad, since it will lead to endless confusion between $\mu$ (the function) and $\mu$ (the summatory function). What happens if you subtract the last value of $\mu$ (the function) from the summatory function $\mu(N)$ of Moebius up to $N$? $\mu(N) - \mu(N) = \mu(N - 1)$? I would argue this strains both my brain and eyes!

Comment: I think you missed the dot over the mu in the suggested notation for the summatory function.

Comment: which shows that the idea of having a dot did not quite make things clearer :-)

Comment: @aosjckajsd   You must have a problem with your browser : I have the point on my screen. As I said the point should be must bigger, I still think this is nice and not ambiguous but habits die hard...Now a dot is mot discrete and as generic as capitalizing a letter but save the M ...

Comment: One problem with a dot is that in some contexts it stands for derivative, but you want to use it for a summation, which is pretty nearly the opposite concept.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I agree, yet in number theory and combinatorics summation is more common that derivative. You are right that in fact Einstein was a user of the point as a derivative as it kept some heavy torsor calculation much lighter. More over the proper usage is $\dot \mu ([1,N]) $ or $\dot \mu ([N]) $ as $M(N)$ .

Comment: I think Newton used it long before Einstein.